# como hacer promesas de Javascript para insertar datos en una tabla con datos Json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

Espero me puedan ayudar con este pequeño problema que no me ha dejado avanzar realmente no se mucho sobre esto y he estado recibiendo ayuda y me ayudaron con promesas de javascript y no se manejarlas, y no puedo avanzar.
al momento de poner un dato en mi input-text este valida si está en la base de datos entonces me abre una ventana modal en la cual tengo otroo input-text donde ingreso otro dato y me agrega la información a la tabla, entonces lo que necesito hacer y espero me ayuden con esto es que al darle aceptar al botón del modal se me agregue la información del primer dato que ingrese en mi primer input-text

**html del primer input-text**

```
<section>

          <input type="text" name="codigo" id="serial" placeholder="Escanear Codigo de Barras del DN" class="codigo"/>

                <button class="btn btn-info " id="descargar" name="descargar">Descargar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
            </section>
            <section class="tsect">
                <table class="grilla" id="tabla">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>NetApp Po</th>
                            <th>Costumer Np</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Rev</th>
                            <th>Boxes by Po</th>
                            <th>Pallet Status</th>
                            <th>DN Equipo</th>
                            <th>create Date Asn</th>
                            <th>Shipping Address</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>So No</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="dnsalida">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
```

**modal que se abre al ingresar un dato**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="scanSerial" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Escanear los S/N</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div>

                            <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" placeholder="Escanear S/N" class="codigo"/>

                            <br>    <br>

                            <section class="tsect">
                                <table class="grilla" id="tabla">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Id</th>
                                            <th>DN</th>
                                            <th>NET APP PO</th>
                                            <th>SERIAL NUMBER</th>
                                            <th>SECOND PPID</th>
                                            <th>SHIPPING SN</th>
                                            <th>MODEL NAME</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="registros">

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </section>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="infoDN" >Aceptar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Script con el que me ayudaron**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var currentDn = null;
            var serials = [];




            // limpia todas las variables globales
            function limpiarGlobales () {
                // currentDn = null;
                serials = [];
            }

            function limpiarTabla() {
                console.log('limpiando tabla');
                $("#tabla tbody").empty();
            }

            function validarDn (value) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    $.post('/pruebas/stark/php/busqueda.php',
                    {
                    value: value
                    },
                    function(data, status){
                            let dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log('data: ' + data);
                            console.log('dataParsed: ' + dataParsed);
                            if (dataParsed.isValid) {
                                currentDn = value;
                            }
                            resolve(dataParsed.isValid);
                });
                })
            }

            // Decidir si abrir modal
            $("#serial").focus();
            $("#serial").on('keyup', function escanDn(e) {
                // console.log('e: ' + JSON.stringify(e))
              var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                console.log('keycode on serial: ' + keycode)
              if (keycode == '13') {
                    // let value = 3090054569;
                    var value = $('#serial').val();
                    // validar DN
                    validarDn(value)
                        .then(isValid => {
                            if (isValid) {
                                limpiarTabla();
                                limpiarGlobales();
                                $('#scanSerial').modal('show');
                            }
                        })
                        .catch();
              }
            });

            function validarCodigo(code) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    $.post('php/buSerial.php',
                    {
                    codigo: code
                    },
                    function(data, status){
                            // let dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                            console.log('currentDn: ' + currentDn);
                            // console.log('dataParsed: ' + dataParsed);

                            if (data.dn == currentDn) {
                                resolve({
                                    isValid: true,
                                    data
                                })
                            }

                            resolve({
                                isValid: false
                            });
                });
                });
            }

            // Decidir si agregar a tabla en modal
            $('#codigo').on('keyup', function checkCode(e) {
                var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (keycode == '13') {
                    var code = $('#codigo').val();
                    validarCodigo(code)
                        .then(result => {
                            console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                            if (result.isValid) {
                                console.log('serials: ' + serials);
                                if (!serials.includes(result.data.serial_number)) {
                                    $('#registros').append($('<tr>')
                                    .append($('<td>').append(result.data.id))
                                    .append($('<td>').append( result.data.dn))
                                    .append($('<td>').append( result.data.po ))
                                    .append($('<td>').append( result.data.serial_number ))
                                    .append($('<td>').append( result.data.second ))
                                    .append($('<td>').append( result.data.shiping_sn ))
                                    .append($('<td>').append( result.data.model ))
                                    );
                                    serials.push(result.data.serial_number);
                                    console.log('serials: ' + serials);
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById('xyz').play();
                                        alert("ERROR Codigo de Serial ya esta Incluido !! ");
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .catch();
                }
            })

            </script>
```

**base de datos**

```
<?php
// BASE DE DATOS
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "baseDatos";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$conexion = null;
$result = [
    'isValid' => false
];

try {
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return json_encode($result);
}

if (!array_key_exists('value', $_POST)) {
    echo json_encode($result);
}

$value = $_POST['value'];

// Consulta 1 en caratulasalida
$sql = "SELECT * FROM caratulasalida WHERE dn = $value";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$r = $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if (count($row) > 0 && $row[0]->pallet_status == 3) {
    $result['isValid'] = true;
}

// Consulta 2 en planproduccion
$sql = "SELECT * FROM planproduccion WHERE dnProduccion = $value";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$r = $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if (count($row) == 0) {
    $result['isValid'] = false;
}

// //consulta 3 en caratula para numFrus
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM caratulasalida where costumer_np = $value";
// $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
// $r = $stmt->execute();
// $row = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//
// if(count($row) != X){
//  $result['isValid']=false;
// }

$conexion = null;

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: @OscarGarcia me podrias ayudar con esto que aun me sigue dando vueltas Por favor

Answer (score 0):

Mira este, intenta con jQuery es muy sencillo aun hacerlo que quieres:

```
//activas un evento al click el boton del modal
$('#infoDN').on('click', function () {
    //capturas el valor del input del modal
    var inputModal = $('codigo').val();
    //seleccionar el input de la tabla y la asignas el valor de la nueva variable
    $('serial').val(inputModal);
});
```

espero te sriva, me avisas

Comment: no me sirvio o creo que aun le falta mas codigo pero lo agregue y no me hace nada no se si le hace falta agregar la tabla o algo asi @srJJ

Comment: te toca es ver en que momento se activa ese script, por que si lo hace cuando carga nunca hara nada

Comment: habro el inspeccionador de elementos y no veo que suceda nada, le puse console.log pero solo en #infoDN sale el console.log ya de los demas no

Comment: se me ocurrio esto pero no me funciono //activas un evento al click el boton del modal
      $('#infoDN').on('click', function () {
          //capturas el valor del input del modal
          var value = $('#serial').val();
        validarDn(value)
         .then(datos => {
          console.log('datos: ' + JSON.stringify(datos));
            $('#registros').append($('<tr>')            .append($('<td>').append(datos.id, '<input type="checkbox" name="dn[]" value="append(datos.id)" checked>'))           .append($('<td>').append( datos.data.net_app_po))

Comment: mejor crea toda la estructura de la fila en una sola variable con sus valores y luego le haces el append

Comment: pero al momento de traer los datos de la base de datos como es que le tengo que hacer ? como te comento arriba no se mucho soy totalmente nuevo en esto, lo que llevo es por que me ayudaron y creo que usaron Ecmascript6 y no entiendo nada la vdd